# Karma.config.js angularjs issues

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to just set up karma unit testing in my angular 1.x application. I've followed 1 million tutorials and still can't get it right. Here is my files array in the karma.config.js:

```
[

    'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
    'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
    'bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js',
    'bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js',
    'bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
    'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
    'bower_components/angular-environment/src/angular-environment.js',
    'site-inStore/app/**/*.js',
    'site-inStore/app.js',
    'site-inStore/app.config.js',
    'site-inStore/app.factory.js',
    'site-inStore/app.networker.js',
    'site-inStore/assets/css/*.cs',
    './test/*.js'
],
```

My module declaration looks like this:

```
var sisApp = angular.module('sisApp', ['ngRoute','ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMessages', 'environment']);
```

And the error I'm getting when I run `karma start` is:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'sisApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

If there are any other details that I'm missing that would help in diagnosing the issue please let me know and I will add whatever needed.

Comment: Is app.js your module declaration? If so that should be the top of your site-inStore list.

Comment: ^ winner winner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to anticipate the actual problem, but I have some tips for you:

For your bower dependencies I would recommend to use [wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#programmatic-access) to maintain your list of bower dependencies.
For your own JS files I would recommend to use the [karma-angular-filesort](https://github.com/wilsonjackson/karma-angular-filesort) plugin.

Also, make sure that you run a `beforeEach(module(<your-module>))` before your test suites for `<your-module>`.

Comment: This would have fixed it originally when I was doing `app/*.js` which was inadvertently compiling my module, configuration and factories in a random order.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it appears the issue is that the call to

```
'site-inStore/app/**/*.js'
```

is attempting to run code that looks for your module. Since your module isn't actually declared until the following line then the error you see would be expected. To make matters even more confusing, depending on the naming of your files, this setup could have worked at one time assuming that the module declaration happened to be run before anything else.

To fix the issue, make sure your module file comes right after all of your dependencies.

Comment: Yes, also, `'site-inStore/app/**/*.js'` already includes `'site-inStore/app.js'`. So, to fix this issue of file ordering I highly recommend to use the karma-angular-filesort plugin, that I've mentioned in my answer.